# How do I implement email dispatch with Drupal Symfony Mailer from scratch?

Tags: emails, symfony-services

I'm implementing a cron job that should send a notification email to all users that meet a certain criterion.
I created a Service implementing the `CronInterface` and `hook_cron` calls this service's `run()` method.
This queries for the users that need notification.
I want to loop over these user and send emails to them.
These emails should contain a default message and they should be greeted with their name.

The system already uses the "Drupal Symfony Mailer".
Everything in the documentation seems to migrate configurations from other implmentations.

I tried implementing a  Plugin extending `EmailBuilderBase` with:

```php
@EmailBuilder(
  id = "notification",
  sub_types = { "update" = @Translation("Update") },
  common_adjusters = {"email_subject", "email_body"},
)
```

My expectation was that I will be able to

- add a new policy on the configuration page that belongs to this class
- provide my notification text, using a token for the user name
- send the email via `Drupal::service('email_factory')->sendTypedEmail('notification', 'update', $user);`

This doesn't work.
I can't create a policy matching my Builder.
The dropdown menus on policy creation don't offer options for "notification" and "update" for the type and sub-type selection.

How do I create the policy that allows me to send my email via the method call above without writing a deprecated version that gets migrated?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean, technically?

Comment: I expected the magic comment to create additional options in the dropdown menus for policy creation. I thought, there might appear an option "notification" for the type and an option "update" for the sub-type, at least after (re-)activating the module and rebuilding the cache. This didn't happen and now I'm stuck. Either something is broken or I got the concept wrong. I updated the discription.

Answer (score 1):

I created a specific type and subtype for a custom module, like this:
In src/Plugin/Emailbuilder create a class MyModuleEmailBuilder extends EmailBuilderBase. Make an annotation there:

```
/**
 * Email Builder plug-in for the custom_email_example module.
 *
 * @EmailBuilder(
 *   id = "my_module",
 *   sub_types = {
 *     "update" = @Translation("Update"),
 *   },
 *   common_adjusters = {"email_subject", "email_body"},
 * )
 */
```

Then (re-)install the module.
Hopes this helps!